# In Excel: What are the corresponding idMso's for these ribbon buttons?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto

I'm now tired of searching & googling for more that 4 days about this!
In my C#/VSTO Addin, I want to know when the user is about to    add a new data to the current workbook, unlike the first 3 buttons    (hilighted in blue), it doesn't seems that the buttons (hilighted in    red) under gallery "From Other Sources" had corresponding idMso,    since I want to get notified when one of them is clicked or at least    subscribe to an excel event which will call my metod back,
So far, ONLY the 3rd "From XML Data Import" seems to have an event in    excel which is **ExcelApp.WorkbookAfterXmlImport**, for the others, I can't find any..
I have read the [ExcelRibbonControls.xlsx](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3582) (for 2010 as well)    without any chance?!
Any help on this?
Thanks in advance,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you searched at the right location - you just chose the *wrong file*. I had a look into the `accessControls.xlsx` file and found these ids. I am confident you can use these idMso's!

[image: AccessControls.xlsx Import idMso]

Comment: Not sure if this will work, I'll test anyway, since these are Access idMso's and I need Excel idMso's! i do not need to track "Dbase", "Paradox","Lotus".. etc however, I need to track "SqlServer","Analysis Services"..etc Any thoughts? maybe via some Excel events?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the gallery control with IdMso **GetExternalDataFromOtherSources**. You will not find IdMso values for the entries marked with red. Try to repurpose the gallery itself.

Comment: yes @Eugene, that's the right idMso for this gallery, I had the same challenge with the gallery "ControlsGalleryClassic" under Developer Tab and even if I was not able to intercept its onAction command, I found that all its elements already have corresponding idMso's like: Form Controls Group: FormControlEditBox, FormControlEditBox and ActiveX Controls-> ActiveXCheckBox, ActiveXButton. I was then able to clone this gallery (and setting original to invisible) with controls with the same pictures and onAction run the corresponding command using this code: Excel.CommandBars.ExecuteMso(id)